# I just downloaded blender 2.7 for an older desktop Mac and the files won't open

Tags: video

My computer(I'm new to working with apple)

Processor  2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory  4 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
Graphics  ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT 128 MB

Blender 2.79, 2.8 wouldn't open on my computer. 
In blender when I go to file. open, the files are empty in blender and are not pulling my files to open. The folders are there but there are no files. Why would this happen? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: For your information, Blender v2.79 is *not* the newest edition of Blender. Try downloading v2.81.

Comment: Could you add a little more information ? Blender can only "open" files that have an extension in .blend. Otherwise if you want to open a file created in another software, you need to create a new .blend file, and choose File>Import

Comment: I tried downloading blender 2.8 and it wouldn't open so I downloaded the older version which opened. Should blender 2.8 work on my type of set up? I couldn't get it to open after download.

Comment: Okay, umm, so if I'm reading this right. Before opening a file I would need to use a file converter to change say an mp3 Video file to a blender file first. I'm mostly right now just doing video editing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think I might try out a different software maybe something more slimed down for video editing. Have a good one.

Comment: You misunderstood what @Gorgious meant, there is a difference between opening and importing files. For example you can make a new .blend project in blender. There you can **import** your mp3 directly (without any inbetween conversion software). Obviously you can later also **export** to your mp3 format after editing.